# procedure compiling in oracle is not working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have written below procedure in oracle but its getting compiled with error.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MIGRATE_ONEIBER 

AS 

BEGIN

-- EXECUTE PROCEDURE ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE;

  execute ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE;

  execute ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_CITY;
  
  execute ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_NLDC;
  
  END;
  


--  NULL;
END PROC_MIGRATE_ONEIBER;
```

I have to execute 3 procedures in one main procedure without any IN or OUT parameters. But its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `execute` keyword. Whenever you want to call another procedure within the procedure you can directly use the procedure name and parameters, If any.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MIGRATE_ONEIBER AS
BEGIN

-- EXECUTE PROCEDURE ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE;
    ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE;
    ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_CITY;
    ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_NLDC;
    --END;

--  NULL;
END PROC_MIGRATE_ONEIBER;
/
```

Update: Check this small code of how it should be. All procedures created in this answer are just for demo. (Make sure that the procedure that you are calling is not `INVALID`)

```
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE AS
  2  BEGIN
  3  NULL;
  4  END;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_CITY AS
  2  BEGIN
  3  NULL;
  4  END;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_NLDC AS
  2  BEGIN
  3  NULL;
  4  END;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MIGRATE_ONEIBER AS
  2  BEGIN
  3  ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE;
  4  ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_CITY;
  5  ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_NLDC;
  6  END PROC_MIGRATE_ONEIBER;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Which error? You must share the error so that I can further help you. I have edited the answer, Commneted the `END`. Please check now!!

Comment: So, Is there any procedure in your schema with this name? It is throwing error that such procedures do not exist in your schema. If the procedure that you are calling is in a different schema then you have to use the `schemaname.procedurename`

Comment: If you are using the same code as written in this answer, then it must not be error'ed out.

Comment: Check the updated answer with sample procedures code.

Comment: YES DONE..!! actually I was calling the wrong procedure name..!! sorry but got it